# Netbeans marks "function print()" as Syntax Error

Tags: php, netbeans, printing, syntax-error

I have some projects that define a print function like this:

```
private function print($msg)  {
  ...
}
```

Netbeans 8.2 shows a Syntax Error "unexpected: print"
But this syntax is allowed and it works with PHP7.

How do I make Netbeans 8.2 ignore this Error ?

Comment: There is bug reported here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262141

Answer (score -1):

Change function name print its php function and can not be used.

Comment: Usage of 'print' (and also 'list') as a function name is allowed and works since PHP 7.0